# Maven properties exapnsion in spring boot tests

Tags: java, yaml

Does maven properties expansion support for spring boot test resources files or not, because I have it works perfectly in application resources application.yml file just like that:

project: @project.name@

Has any one faced same problem before?

Comment: Take a look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398179/maven-properties-expansion-only-works-for-base-application-properties/60414077#60414077