# Maven properties expansion only works for base application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I added the spring-boot-starter as parent project according to this:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-auto-property-expansion

property expansion works well from the base application.properties file:

```
someProp = @project.version@
```

will become: `someProp=4.3`

but once I want to use this in application-test.properties it couldnt resolve the expansion mark '@' and resolves it to a raw string and will become: `someProp=@project.version@`

Is there any way to bind maven property to any properties file?

Comment: Where you have you put your `application-test.properties` ?

Comment: src/test/resources

Comment: should work if you are using it with `test` as the active profile. `@ActiveProfiles("test")` on your test-class or start your app environment variable with  `-Dspring.profiles.active=test`

Comment: It runs with test profile, but doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. 
Tutorials doesn't mention it , but official document does:
[Springdoc properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-properties-and-configuration)
So basically automatic property expansion doesn't touch the src/test/resources folder.
Have to setup the filtering by hand:

```
    <build>
      ...
      <testResources>
           <testResource>
               <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
           </testResource>
      </testResources>
    </build>

   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>                  
          <delimiters>
            <delimiter>@</delimiter>
          </delimiters>
          <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: Good work digging this up on your own. I saw this this morning and was about to answer the question with the exact sentiment.